# Polynomial factors involving inequalities

Tags: inequality, polynomials, factoring

How to factorise the polynomial $p(x) = x^4-2x^3 + 2x - 1$.

Hence, solve the inequality $p(x) \gt 0$ ?

Comment: Do you know the rational root thorem?

Comment: i seriously have no idea what that is... could you be a little more precise.

Comment: Well, it says that every rational root of a polynomial is of the form $$\frac{\text{Divisor of the constant term}}{\text{Divisor of the leading coeffcient}}$$ In this case the constant term is $-1$ the leading coefficient is $1$ (from the $x^4$). So you just have to try if $-1$ or $1$ are roots. Both are.

Comment: so i have to juz put in the roots -1 or 1, to see if it is equal to zero or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First factor:
\begin{align}
p(x)=x^4-2x^3+2x-1 &=x^4-2x^3+x^2-x^2+2x-1 & \text{add and subtract $x^2$} \\
&=x^2(x^2-2x+1)-1(x^2-2x+1) & \text{group the terms}\\
&=(x^2-1)(x^2-2x+1) & \text{factor by grouping} \\
&=[(x+1)(x-1)][(x-1)^2] & \text{factor even more} \\
&=(x+1)(x-1)^3 & \text{simplify}
\end{align}
Next we need to find critical points, so for now set $p(x) = 0$: $$p(x)=(x+1)(x-1)^3 =0$$
which implies $(x+1)=0$ and $(x-1)^3=0$. Hence, $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are solutions to $p(x)=0$. Those will be your critical points on the number line, like this:

$\hskip0.9in$[image]

And test each region separated by the critical points. For example, plug in $x=0$ into $p(x)$, if you want to test region $(-1,1)$.

- For region $(-\infty,-1)$, $p(x) > 0$.
- For region $(-1,1)$, $p(x) < 0$.
- For region $(1,\infty)$, $p(x) > 0$.

(Verify these by plugging in some $x$ values into $p(x)$!)

So, your solution set is $\boxed{(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)}$.

Answer (score 0):

See that $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are roots of this polynomial. Then factorization would be easy. See $p(x)=(x+1)^3(x-1)$

Then for $p(x) \gt 0$, you must have $x \gt 1$ or $x \lt -1$.

Comment: Do you know how to factories it...Could you help me? i Couldn't solve it..

Answer (score 0):

We see an obvious root $-1$ : $P(-1)=1+2-2-1=0$

Therefore it can be factorized by $(X+1)$

$P(X)=(X+1)(X-1)^3$

Thus $P(X)>0$ when $x\in\left[-\infty,-1\right[\cup\left]1,+\infty\right[$

Answer (score 0):

$p(x) = (x-1)^3(x+1)$. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

The "nice" way to do it: add and subtract $x^2$ to get
$$\eqalign{x^4-2x^3+2x-1
  &=x^4-2x^3+x^2-x^2+2x-1\cr
  &=(x^4-2x^3+x^2)-(x^2-2x+1)\cr
  &=(x^2-1)(x^2-2x+1)\cr}$$
and the rest should be easy.

Comment: So when i complete the factorization i would get (x+1)(x-1)^3..Thank You so much for your help..

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)=x^4-2x^3+2x-1$
$$= x^4-1^2-2x^3+2x$$
$$=(x^2)^2-1^2-2x(x^2-1)$$
$$=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)-2x(x+1)(x-1)$$
$$=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)-2x(x+1)(x-1)$$
$$=(x+1)(x-1)(x^2-2x+1)$$
$$=(x+1)(x-1)(x^2-x-x+1)$$
$$=(x+1)(x-1)(x(x-1)-1(x-1))$$
$$=(x+1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)$$
$$=(x+1)(x-1)^3$$
Thus $x=1,-1$

Comment: thank you for your help....i got the answer ...i appreciate it so much..

Comment: @cynitha Never mind